# Limiting Access to Endpoints by Method in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

We are implementing a simple health check API our load balancers can call to help with the routing of requests. If the status of the application is "standby", requests should not be sent to it. Only the admins can set the state to "up" or "standby", but anyone (including the load balancers) can get the status of the application.

We are trying this with Spring Boot 2, but are having problems configuring security to grant anonymous access to just one of the routes. Consider the following controller:

```java
@RestController
public class AppStatusController {

    private static final String STATUS = "status";
    String state = "standby";

    private String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    private Map<String, String> getStatusMap() {
        Map<String, String> retval = new HashMap<>();
        retval.put(STATUS, getState());
        return retval;
    }

    // GET calls are public, all others require AuthN & AuthZ
    @GetMapping(path = "/appstatus", produces = "application/json")
    public Map<String, String> getStatus() {
        return getStatusMap();
    }

    // Only those with the ADMIN role can POST to this endpoint
    @PostMapping(path = "/appstatus", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public Map<String, String> setStatus(@RequestBody Map state) {
        // Validate and update the state
        return getStatusMap();
    }
}
```

There is only one endpoint, `/appstatus`, but one method is called with an HTTP GET and the other with an HTTP POST. We want calls to `getStatus` to be public, but allow Spring Security to control access to `setStatus`. One might expect an annotation such as `@Anonymous` or something similar to be applied to the `getStatus()` method but we can't seem to find one.

Some have suggested using a separate `@Configuration` class and setting up  `antMatchers` but it's not clear how we can match on the HTTP method.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to configure Spring Security to allow public access to GET method requests but control access to other methods?

EDIT: We are trying to avoid any authentication on the `getStatus()` call. We can't store auth credentials in the health check probe and can't perform a login exchange. This is a simple GET request to see if the application is up and ready for operation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Method Security Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#method-security-expressions)?

It looks like this will do what you want:

```
    // GET calls are public, all others require AuthN & AuthZ
    @GetMapping(path = "/appstatus", produces = "application/json")
    @PreAuthorize("permitAll")
    public Map<String, String> getStatus() {
        return getStatusMap();
    }

    // Only those with the ADMIN role can POST to this endpoint
    @PostMapping(path = "/appstatus", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public Map<String, String> setStatus(@RequestBody Map state) {
        // Validate and update the state
        return getStatusMap();
    }
```

Note: I don't know what roles your admins have, so I used 'ADMIN' as a placeholder.

Comment: The use of `@PreAuthorize` still requires the login of the requester which is not possible with the simple health check probe. The use of `hasRole` is good and will be used going forward. - Thanks